# Separate a String By Semicolon

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, unrecognized-selector

I am using following code to separate a string into multiple strings and getting an error

```
NSArray *arr = [randomStr componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

Error:

> -[__NSDictionaryM componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1758f230
>   -[__NSDictionaryM componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1758f230

This is my Sample Data

```
NSArray *data = {
    {
    name = "name1";
    address = "RWP";
    ID = 0;
},
    {
    name = "name2";
    address = "RWP";
    ID = 1;
},
    {
    name = "name3";
    address = "RWP";
    ID = 2;
},}

NSString *randomStr = data[0];
```

What's wrong in my code

Comment: randomStr not a string object you can check by using `isKindOfClass` method.

Comment: randomStr can be any string.. it is not a dictionary

Comment: The error clearly states that `randomStr` is a mutable dictionary (`NSMutableDictionary`).

Comment: You should update your question to show how you assign a value to `randomStr`. That's what you need to fix.

Comment: @rmaddy i updated my question now check please!

Comment: Clearly `data` is an array of dictionaries. Why are you assigning a dictionary to a string variable?

Comment: @rmaddy this is only how i know is to be achieved, i am new to ios programming so i am not very expert of doing things

Comment: thats how confusing works .... but great that you found a solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an array of dictionaries, not strings. There is nothing to split.

You want something like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = data[0];
NSString *name = dict[@"name"];
NSString *address = dict[@"address"];
```

Comment: ok Thankyou i get what was problem, thanks for your sample code, it made my work more easy

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the randomStr variable is an MutableDictionary. Thats why its not working.

here is my Test:

```
NSString *foo = @"BAR;FOO;VAR";
NSArray *arr = [foo componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
NSLog(@"%@", arr);
```

Thise Logs:

```
BAR,
FOO,
VAR
```

**EDIT:** 
Dictionary to array:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = @{@"aKey1" :@"BAR",
                              @"aKey2" :@"FOO",
                              @"aKey3" :@"VAR"}.mutableCopy;

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *key in dict) {
    [array addObject:dict[key]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

This Logs:

```
BAR,
FOO,
VAR
```

Comment: ok so how i am suppose to separate tha MutableDictionary by ";"

Comment: So you have an NSMutableDictionary and you want an Array that lists the Value of this Dictionary? Can you please Post your dictionary filling code?
Otherwise you need to loop the dictionary, and putt every value as a new object in the MutableArray.

Comment: i added the dictionary to array thing in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to be sure randomStr as a NSString.
You can check like

```
if ([randomStr isKindOfClass:[NSString Class]]) {

    NSArray *arr = [randomStr componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
 }
```

Comment: isn`t the function "componentsSeparatedByString" only appearing in NSString?